# How do i subtract a number from a textfile with the date +%s number using a script?

Tags: scripting

I want to be able to subtract two numbers where the first number is the date +%s number with a number that i have stored in a textfile, but im unsure how to do that since im very new to linux and writing scripts.

My code so far is:

```
date +%s
filename='datefile'
n=1
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < filename
```

This gives me the two numbers that i want to subtract. I'm not sure if the whole while loop is a good way of getting the number from the file and I have no idea how to subtract the two numbers. Is it possible to store these two numbers in two variables and use the variables for the subtraction?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help , first point about code blocks

Answer (score 0):

If the file has only that timestamp, and no other content, it's easier to just use [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`$(...)`) to read the whole file. Similarly you can take the output of `date +%s`. [Arithmetic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) can be done within `$(( .. ))`.

```
t1=$(date +%s)
t0=$(cat datefile)
echo $(( t1 - t0 ))
```

Comment: Yeah, that works much better, i added an x="$line" and echo "$x" to my loop to get that number but this way was much easier. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Or just `read t0 <datefile` to read the stored timestamp.